# How to pivot pandas dataframe (with two headers)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks as follows:

| Age | USA | USA | USA | UK | UK | UK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Age** | **male** | **female** | **total** | **male** | **female** | **total** |
| 2-year-old | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3-year-old | 8 | 8 | 16 | 7 | 9 | 16 |

In fact I have two row headers (USA + male; USA + female;..)

CSV-File (test.csv):

```
;USA;USA;USA;UK;UK;UK
Age;male;female;total;male;female;total
2-year-old;2;3;5;1;1;2
3-year-old;8;8;16;7;9;16
```

My python-code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', 
                 delimiter=";",
                 header=[0,1])

df = df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0_level_0': 'Age'})
```

How to pivot pandas dataframe to get the following result?

| Age | Country | Gender | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2-year-old | USA | male | 2 |
| 2-year-old | USA | female | 3 |
| 2-year-old | UK | male | 1 |
| 2-year-old | UK | female | 1 |
| 3-year-old | USA | male | 8 |
| 3-year-old | USA | female | 8 |
| 3-year-old | UK | male | 7 |
| 3-year-old | UK | female | 9 |

**EDIT:**

Starting Table:

| Kode | Country | Procedure | male | male | female | female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kode | Country | Procedure | two-year-old | three-year-old | two-year-old | three-year-old |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 6 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 1b | US | proc_2 | 15 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 1b | UK | proc_2 | 8 | 4 | 7 | 3 |

CSV:

```
Code;Country;Procedure;male;male;female;female
Code;Country;Procedure;two-year-old;three-year-old;two-year-old;three-year-old
1a;US;proc_1;4;6;3;6
1a;UK;proc_1;2;3;5;1
1b;US;proc_2;15;3;5;2
1b;UK;proc_2;8;4;7;3
```

Resulting Table:

| Code | Country | Procedure | Gender | Age | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | male | two-year-old | 4 |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | male | three-year-old | 6 |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | female | two-year-old | 3 |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | female | three-year-old | 6 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | male | two-year-old | 2 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | male | three-year-old | 3 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | female | two-year-old | 5 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | female | three-year-old | 1 |
| 1b | ... |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), also if need remove total add `drop`:

```
df = (df.drop('total', axis=1, level=1)
        .set_index(df.columns[0])
        .stack([0,1])
        .rename_axis(['Age','Country','Gender'])
        .reset_index(name='frequency'))
print (df)
          Age Country  Gender  frequency
0  2-year-old      UK  female          1
1  2-year-old      UK    male          1
2  2-year-old     USA  female          3
3  2-year-old     USA    male          2
4  3-year-old      UK  female          9
5  3-year-old      UK    male          7
6  3-year-old     USA  female          8
7  3-year-old     USA    male          8
```

Or:

```
df = (df.set_index(df.columns[0])
        .stack([0,1])
        .rename_axis(['Age','Country','Gender'])
        .reset_index(name='frequency'))
print (df)
           Age Country  Gender  frequency
0   2-year-old      UK  female          1
1   2-year-old      UK    male          1
2   2-year-old      UK   total          2
3   2-year-old     USA  female          3
4   2-year-old     USA    male          2
5   2-year-old     USA   total          5
6   3-year-old      UK  female          9
7   3-year-old      UK    male          7
8   3-year-old      UK   total         16
9   3-year-old     USA  female          8
10  3-year-old     USA    male          8
11  3-year-old     USA   total         16
```

Comment: Hello jezreal. Could you pls have a look at my edited question. How would I get the required output in this case? Thanks.

Comment: @dublin123 - I will be offline now, can you post new question?

Comment: Okay, thanks:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69854112/how-to-pivot-pandas-dataframe