# How to unpivot pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks as follows:
Starting Table:

| Kode | Country | Procedure | male | male | female | female |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Kode | Country | Procedure | two-year-old | three-year-old | two-year-old | three-year-old |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | 4 | 6 | 3 | 6 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 1 |
| 1b | US | proc_2 | 15 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 1b | UK | proc_2 | 8 | 4 | 7 | 3 |

CSV:

```
Code;Country;Procedure;male;male;female;female
Code;Country;Procedure;two-year-old;three-year-old;two-year-old;three-year-old
1a;US;proc_1;4;6;3;6
1a;UK;proc_1;2;3;5;1
1b;US;proc_2;15;3;5;2
1b;UK;proc_2;8;4;7;3
```

My python code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', 
                 header=[0,1],delimiter= ';',
                 engine='python', 
                 encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

In fact I have two row headers
How to pivot pandas dataframe to get the following result?

Resulting Table:

| Code | Country | Procedure | Gender | Age | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | male | two-year-old | 4 |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | male | three-year-old | 6 |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | female | two-year-old | 3 |
| 1a | US | proc_1 | female | three-year-old | 6 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | male | two-year-old | 2 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | male | three-year-old | 3 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | female | two-year-old | 5 |
| 1a | UK | proc_1 | female | three-year-old | 1 |
| 1b | ... |  |  |  |  |

Comment: hey @dublin123, try this: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: This so called stack

Answer (score 3):

You'll likely want to [go with `melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) which is sort of the *opposite* of pivot.

- We specify the identifer variables: the first three columns
- The rest of the columns become value variables and we assign them names, and a name for the new value column

```
import io
import pandas as pd

piv = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Code;Country;Procedure;male;male;female;female
Code;Country;Procedure;two-year-old;three-year-old;two-year-old;three-year-old
1a;US;proc_1;4;6;3;6
1a;UK;proc_1;2;3;5;1
1b;US;proc_2;15;3;5;2
1b;UK;proc_2;8;4;7;3"""), header=[0, 1], delimiter=";")


unpivoted = piv.melt(id_vars=list(piv.columns[:3]),
                     var_name=['gender', 'age'],
                     value_name='frequency')

# cleanup the tupleized columns
unpivoted.columns = [(col[0] if isinstance(col, tuple) else col)
                     for col in unpivoted.columns]
```