# How to deal with double header dataframe and pivot it in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a data frame as follows:

```
Country Year    Stunting prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)  Stunting prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)  Stunting prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)  Stunting prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)  Stunting prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)  Underweight prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)   Underweight prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)   Underweight prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)   Underweight prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)   Underweight prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)
        Q1 (Poorest)    Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5 (Richest)    Q1 (Poorest)    Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5 (Richest)
Albania 2017    17.1 [14.3-20.2]    10.5 [7.6-14.3] 7.3 [4.8-10.8]  11.3 [7.6-16.6] 9.2 [5.1-15.8]  2.4 [1.5-3.9]   1.2 [0.6-2.3]   0.9 [0.3-2.7]   2.0 [0.6-6.3]   0.7 [0.2-2.1]
Albania 2008    31.5 [24.9-39.1]    24.9 [18.3-32.9]    20.0 [15.3-25.7]    21.9 [17.6-27.0]    16.2 [12.0-21.4]    9.2 [5.8-14.1]  5.6 [3.4-9.1]   6.6 [3.8-11.0]  5.4 [3.2-9.0]   4.0 [2.2-7.3]
Albania 2005    35.2 [29.2-41.6]    28.0 [21.4-35.7]    28.3 [21.8-35.9]    22.0 [16.5-28.6]    18.1 [13.5-23.8]    11.8 [7.8-17.6] 7.5 [4.6-12.1]  7.6 [4.6-12.2]  2.5 [1.2-5.2]   2.8 [1.3-5.8]
```

It's part of the df that can be found [here](https://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.main.nHE-1559?lang=en).

I want this data frame to look like the following:

```
Country Year    Quarter Stunting prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)  Underweight prevalence in children aged < 5 years (%)
Albania 2017    Q1  17.1 [14.3-20.2]    2.4 [1.5-3.9]
Albania 2017    Q2  10.5 [7.6-14.3] 1.2 [0.6-2.3]
Albania 2017    Q3  7.3 [4.8-10.8]  0.9 [0.3-2.7]
Albania 2017    Q4  11.3 [7.6-16.6] 2.0 [0.6-6.3]
Albania 2017    Q5  9.2 [5.1-15.8]  0.7 [0.2-2.1]
Albania 2008    Q1  31.5 [24.9-39.1]    9.2 [5.8-14.1]
Albania 2008    Q2  24.9 [18.3-32.9]    5.6 [3.4-9.1]
Albania 2008    Q3  20.0 [15.3-25.7]    6.6 [3.8-11.0]
Albania 2008    Q4  21.9 [17.6-27.0]    5.4 [3.2-9.0]
Albania 2008    Q5  16.2 [12.0-21.4]    4.0 [2.2-7.3]
Albania 2005    Q1  35.2 [29.2-41.6]    11.8 [7.8-17.6]
Albania 2005    Q2  28.0 [21.4-35.7]    7.5 [4.6-12.1]
Albania 2005    Q3  28.3 [21.8-35.9]    7.6 [4.6-12.2]
Albania 2005    Q4  22.0 [16.5-28.6]    2.5 [1.2-5.2]
Albania 2005    Q5  18.1 [13.5-23.8]    2.8 [1.3-5.8]
```

I've tried the following code:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv('wealthQuintileData.csv', header=[0, 1])
df3 = (df2.set_index(df.columns[0]).stack([0, 1]).rename_axis(['Country', 'Measure', 'Quarter']).reset_index(name='Value'))
```

This code gives me following result:

```
Country Measure Quarter Value
0   (Albania,)  Overweight prevalence in children aged < 5 yea...   Q1 (Poorest)    14.7 [12.2-17.6]
1   (Albania,)  Overweight prevalence in children aged < 5 yea...   Q2  16.8 [13.6-20.5]
2   (Albania,)  Overweight prevalence in children aged < 5 yea...   Q3  16.5 [12.1-22.0]
3   (Albania,)  Overweight prevalence in children aged < 5 yea...   Q4  17.2 [12.4-23.2]
4   (Albania,)  Overweight prevalence in children aged < 5 yea...   Q5 (Richest)    17.4 [12.1-24.4]
```

Here the year is missing. How can I deal with this. I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69851845/how-to-pivot-pandas-dataframe-with-two-headers) answer.

Comment: it is very hard to read the original dataframe and make sense of it (I know that that is part of your problem as well, but makes it very hard for us). It would help us if you give a much smaller example, which fewer columns with shorter names and explain what the structure is you are dealing with

Comment: Your columns are a multi-index. The pandas user guide explains how to work with these quite nicely; https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: 1. `df2.set_index(df.columns[0])` can be avoided by passing `index_col=[0]` into `read_csv`. 2. You only need to stack one level, not both: `.stack(level=1)`.